# which is better for performance && #memory

Tags: flutter, dart

in my app i need a same divider re-use more than 20+ time . so which way should i follow !!!!!!!

way 1 ........

```
class DividerX extends StatelessWidget {
const DividerX({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Divider(
color: Colors.green,
height: 22,

);
}
}
```

way 2 .......................

```
class DividerX {
const DividerX._();

static const Widget divider = Divider(

 color: Colors.green,
  height: 22,
);
}
```

which is better for #performance && #memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those classes are optimized for good performance as they use the `const` property to tell flutter to update only widgets in the tree that need to be updated. Constants are immutable so flutter doesn't bother updating them. That saves resources which makes your UI fast and snappy overall. However, there are mild advantages to the second class for 2 reasons:

1. It's static and doesn't need to create instance to access its widget. In terms of performance, its a bit better compared to the second class which creates its own instance.
2. It doesn't call additional `build` function like the first class. This is good because it avoids redundancy, which is the objective of your initial reason for implementing this solution anyways.